# Adding code coverage to async node.js mocha tests in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, webstorm

I am trying to set up code coverage for my node.js unit tests.

What I am trying to do is this:

- Use WebStorm for running tests
- use Mocha (and co-mocha) as a testing framework
- Use yield and generators for making my test code more readable
- See the code coverage of my source code via the WebStorm UI (hoping to see my source code files color-coded according to code coverage)

The first two points are going fine, the third one is tripping me up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately WebStorm doesn't provide coverage support for Mocha:( Please follow [WEB-10373](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10373) for updates